# After Installing the react-native-fast-image package the build fails

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have added the package react-native-fast-image to my react project which intents faster caching to load images based on priority in a faster way. Also, i have manually linked the libraries as stated here: 
https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/blob/master/docs/installation-manual.md

But the build fails.[image: And i get the below error as shown in the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As per error, I think you haven't did a setup into native xCode. Follow the below steps to link into xCode.

```
In Xcode:

Add FastImage.xcodeproj to Libraries.

Add libFastImage.a to Link Binary With Libraries under Build Phases.
```

Don't forgot to link before doing the setup.

1) Need to drag from node_modules->react-native-fast-image->ios->FastImage.xcodeproj into under **Libraries**  folder into xcode.

[image]

2) Add libFastImage.a into **Link Binary with Libraries** section.

[image]

Comment: I do have added the fastimage.xcodeproj to my main project libraries. And also have added the libfastimage.a file to my main project's build phase in link binary with libraries. Can you clarify whether libfastimage.a file has to be added under the build phase of main project or under the fastimage.xcodeproj?

Comment: check my response below. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this??

Comment: Delete the application and run from xcode. And then let me know

Comment: Have done the same. But still the same error pops up after the build.